# How to convert from Y-up coordinate system to Z-up blender system?

Tags: python, animation, axis

I try to write owner importer for blender on python, but my matrices are made for Y-up system, so how to convert it to Z-up blender system?
After importing I rotate my armature 90 degrees on the X axis, but do I need to do anything with the animation matrices that define the location and quaternion or will blender do this automatically?

May be i need to multiply it by rotation matrix?

**For example i have this matrix:**

```
Matrix((
    (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00032),
    (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.1003),
    (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.006701),
    (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0))
)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you simply need to rotate $90°$ around $x$ axis?

[image]

[image]

```py
>>> mat = Matrix((
...     (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00032),
...     (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.1003),
...     (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.006701),
...     (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0))
... )
>>> C.object.matrix_world = mat
>>> e  = Euler((pi/2, 0,0))
>>> mat_r = e.to_matrix().to_4x4()
>>> C.object.matrix_world = mat_r @ mat
```

Your matrix then becomes:

```py
>>> mat_r @ mat
Matrix(((1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00031999999191612005),
        (0.0, -4.371138828673793e-08, -1.0, -0.006701047997921705),
        (0.0, 1.0, -4.371138828673793e-08, 1.1002999544143677),
        (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)))
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! But why we multiply mat_r @ mat instead of mat @ mat_r? And do i need to do this for every keyframe matrix and for each matrix of bone for t-pose or only to root bone?

Comment: @SWR the order of operations depends on what you want to do, try both to see the difference - it either offsets first then rotates, or rotates first then offsets. In other words it either rotates in place (around its own origin, which is at world origin before offset) or it rotates around world origin.